# mongo-scala-driver: returning an iterator of results

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I am using [Mongo Scala Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver-scala/tutorials/perform-read-operations/) to read documents from MongoDb. I have following method as follow which returns `Future[List[T]]`

```
def findAll(): List[Future[List[T]] = {
   db.getCollection(collectionName)
      .find(queryObject)
      .toFuture()
      .map{
        results => results.map(/* converting result to T */).toList
      }
}
```

**Question:**

Instead of a List, is there some way, this method can return `Iterator[T]` or `Future[Iterator[T]]` ?

The doc mentions about `iterating the results via the subscribe method`, but I cannot find any concrete implementation or examples of using this `subscribe` method to achieve my use case.

Comment: There is documentation and example for `subscribe` at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver-scala/reference/observables/

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the reference. The explained implementation would be returning Unit. So, could I transform it in such a way that it would return `Iterator[T]` ? I can't put all the logic inline within this method and therefore I need this method to return the Iterator. And, I want to achieve that functionally. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to stream this? If it is not terribly large data, using `toFuture` will be easier to use. If you really want to use streaming, best use a library for that such as Monix Observables or ZIO Stream. They will have adapters for the callbacks that the Mongo driver uses. But that's a bit of a learning curve if you haven't used those before.

Comment: " I can't put all the logic inline within this method " You could pass a callback (of the form `Document => Unit`) into the method. Your logic would then be called for each document.

Comment: @Thilo "Do you really need to stream this?" . Yes, I have to feed the result as a Source to a streaming process. Therefore, I need an iterator.

Comment: What streaming process is that? Cannot the `Source` be driven by the document-consuming callback that the Mongo driver wants?

Comment: @Thilo It's an Akka Stream.

Comment: @Thilo The method signature to build a source is `Source.fromIterator` where signature is `def fromIterator[T](f: () => Iterator[T])`

Comment: There is an adapter for MongoDB to Akka Stream: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/mongodb.html It uses the Java driver instead of the Scala one, but it has things like `val source: Source[Number, NotUsed] =
  MongoSource(numbersColl.find(classOf[Number]))` This is built on `Source.fromPublisher`

Comment: The latest **Mongo** **Scala** driver is based on **reactive streams** which can be easily converted to a `Source` - An advice, never focus on a particular solution but rather on the real problem you want to solve a `Future[Iterator]` would not really be streaming.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Can you please be more specific ? How can it be easily converted ? We are here to learn so sharing helps :) And, another question, how `Future[Iterator]` would not really be streaming ? What purpose would an Iterator solve other than streaming behavior and not loading everything up in memory at once ? May be I am missing something

Comment: @oblivion By just calling `Source.fromPublisher` check the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#fromPublisher[T](publisher:org.reactivestreams.Publisher[T]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]). A `Future[Iterator]` means that you have an async process that produced an **Iterator** since such async process is pulling the DB that means that by the time the **Future** completes all the data is in memory, as such the iterator is not really streaming; unless the **Iterator** will pull the DB again, but then it would be blocking the async process.

Comment: Thanks, using `Source. fromPublisher ` works beautifully !!